# XML with .NET - Build in code or read from a file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml, vb.net

I am building a web application that will generate charts and graphs using a 3rd party charting component. This charting component requires it receive an XML file containing the design parameters and data in order to render the chart. The application may render up to 10 to 20 charts per page view. I am looking for suggestions for the most efficient way to handle this.

I need to load XML templates, of which there will be about 15-20, one for each chart type definition. With the templates loaded, I will them add the chart specific data and send it off to the charting component for rendering. Some of the possible ways of handling this off the top of my head include ->

1. Build each XML template in code, using StringBuilder
2. Build each XML template in code, using one of the .NET XML classes
3. Store each XML template in a file, load it from the disk on demand
4. Store each XML template in a file, load them all at once on application start

Storing the XML templates in files would greatly simplify the development processes for me, but I don't know what kind of performance hit I would take, especially if I was continually reading them off the disk. It seems like option 4 would be the better way to go, but I'm not quite sure the best practice way to implement that solution.

So.. any thoughts out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just taking a crack at it but I'd save the templates into a constant like so and then use string.format to substitute any values and convert to XML file and pass it along to the 3rd party component.

```
const string cChart1 = @"<chart type='pie'>
    <total>{0}</total>
    <sections count={1}>
        <section>{2}</section>
        <section>{3}</section>
        <section>{4}</section>
    </section>
    </chart>";

    XmlDocument xmlChart1 = new XmlDocument();
    xmlChart1.LoadXML(String.format(cChart1, somevalue1, somevalue2, somevalue3, somevalue4, somevalue5));

    3rdPartyChartComponent cc = new 3rdPartyChartComponent(xmlChart1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your suggestions everyone.

I created a test application that ran x number of trials for each of the suggested methods to see which performed best. As it turns out, building the XML string directly using StringBuilder was orders of magnitude faster, unsurprisingly.

Involving an XmlDocument in any way greatly reduced performance. It should be noted that my results were based off of running thousands of trials for each method... but in a practical sense, any of these method are fast enough to do the job right, in my opinion.

Of course, building everything using StringBuilder is a bit on the messy side. I like Jarealist's suggestion, it's a lot easier on the eyes, and if I handle the XML as a string throughout rather than loading it into an XmlDocument, its one of the fastest ways to go.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you can tell the compiler to bundle those XML files inside your CLR exe. Reading from these would not imply a noticeable performance hit as they would be already in memory. You will need to research a bit as i cant get the code out of my head right now, too sleepy.

EDIT.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f45fce5x(v=vs.100).aspx - More info on the subject.

Another benefit from using this approach is that the CLR can guarantee the readability and existance of those files, else your executable will be corrupt and wont run.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will investigate that route.

Answer (score 0):

Are the same templates used more than once? You could store the template as a static variable. Then add a property getter that builds the template (I would probably use your #2) if it hasn't yet been created, and then return it.

This would impose a performance hit the first time the template is used and be very fast after that.

Comment: Yes, they will all be used multiple times in multiple places. I am kind of hoping to avoid building the XML in code if possible though, because it would be much easier to store the templates in files that are copied/pasted off the component's sample pages. I'm not trying to be lazy, I would just prefer not create a bunch of extra work for myself unless it will result in a significant performance benefit.